# Change invoice status to paid programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice

How can we programmatically change the status of an invoice to `Paid` for an order with an offline payment method (eg bank transfer or cash)?

I have tried using the following capture method but this still leaves the invoice as `Pending`:

```
$order->load($_POST['order']);
$order->getPayment()->capture();
$order->save();
```

So how can we update an invoice with an offline payment method to `Paid`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load(...id_of_invoice...);
$invoice->pay()->save();
```

Comment: With that code I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function hasForcedState() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php on line 405`

Comment: For reference, the payment method of the invoice I am trying to update is "Check / Money Order" (checkmo).

Comment: Does this order has payment? Looks like line `$this->getOrder()->getPayment()->hasForcedState()` is causing the problem.

Comment: The order doesn't have payment as it's an offline payment method. It's an order with a pending invoice that we want to mark as paid (we changed the payment method from online credit card to offline as the customer paid by phone).

Comment: So in this case I would suggest this solution : `$invoice->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::STATE_PAID)->save()`

Comment: I swapped the second line of your suggested code with that new line, but now we get the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php on line 956`

Comment: Problem here : `$this->setBillingAddressId($this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getId());`, means that billing address is not set to address. Very strange. How the order was created? Directly by some customer in frontend?

Comment: I am running it on a test order that I created on the frontend as a normal customer. The invoice is currently pending and billing address is fully populated...